# How to make Clickhouse Materialized View work correctly on a cluster with 6 nodes

Tags: distributed, clickhouse, materialized-views

There is 6 nodes in my clickhouse cluster. I create local tables(with ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree engine) and distributed tables on the cluster. A Materialized View on node 'cdh03' is created to join data from tables and write the result to the distributed table. I then create a Materialized View on node 'cdh06', which select data from the distributed table and push them to mysql, with a mysql engine.

However, since data is correctly writen to the distributed table, and could be seen on other nodes, the Materialized View on node 'cdh06' writes nothing to mysql.

I tried to create the Materialized View with the same query on other nodes, but only on the node 'cdh03' it works correctly. What's wrong with this? And what can I do to make it work?

Comment: look at this article https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: + https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/materialized-views/